# Print GMT+00:00 in DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, timezone, date-format, timezone-offset, datetimeformatter

I need to print the date something like `"Fri Feb 24 2023 13:57:11 GMT+00:00"`
with

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d u H:m:s O", Locale.ENGLISH);
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.of("+05:30"));
String strDate = odt.format(dtf);
```

I can print it like `"Fri Feb 24 2023 19:27:11 GMT+5:30".`

But if I use

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.of("+00:00"));
```

it prints as `"Fri Feb 24 2023 13:57:11 GMT"` without the `+00:00`
How could I add that in java?

Comment: Of course I could manually hard code and append +00:00

Comment: using the offset O says this in the java doc, `Four letters outputs the full form, which is localized offset text, such as 'GMT, with 2-digit hour and minute field, optional second field if non-zero, and colon, for example 'GMT+08:00'` so since its zero, the +00:00 is not going to be output, since its optional. This should also apply to using O once only

Comment: Do you understand that having `GMT` *and* `+00:00` is redundant?

Comment: If I use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d u H:m:s 'GMT'xxx", Locale.ENGLISH)` in conjunction with `OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC)`, I get `Fri Feb 24 2023 13:57:11 GMT+00:00`.

Comment: @BasilBourque yes, but downstream needs it this way :)

Comment: @experimentunit1998X Thanks for referring to [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). I believe the relevant sentence from that paragraph is: *If the offset is zero, only localized text is output.*

Comment: I agree with @BasilBourque and I also [commented the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75992230/print-gmt0000-in-datetimeformatter/75993831#comment134032792_75993831) but I missed to see his comment earlier. `GMT+00:00` is not a standard way and to accommodate this requirement, we can customise the pattern (by adding `xxx` or `XXX`) as I have done in my answer.

Comment: I suggest you educate those “downstream” folks about [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 2):

### Avoid hardcoding localized zone-offset

Avoid hardcoding localized zone-offset (e.g. 'GMT'). The [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) already provides you with pattern `O` to deal with localized zone-offset.

**Demo:**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(2023, 1, 24, 13, 57, 11);
        Date date = calendar.getTime();

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d u H:m:s Oxxx", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC);
        String strDate = zdt.format(dtf);
        System.out.println(strDate);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Fri Feb 24 2023 13:57:11 GMT+00:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/wQPGv1)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: This will print `Wed Apr 12 2023 14:44:41 GMT+5+05:00` if the zone offset is "+05:00".

Comment: @MissChanandlerBong - That's not a requirement. The OP has already mentioned `I can print it like "Fri Feb 24 2023 19:27:11 GMT+5:30"` i.e. the OP does not have a problem with a different offset. This answer fulfils the requirement precisely.

Comment: You're right. It fulfills the requirements for a special case, but it also can't be used in a more general case.

Comment: I agree with @MissChanandlerBong that using a formatter that can produce `GMT+5+05:00` is wrong and confusing. If you want to avoid hardcoding the abbreviation -- which is nice -- I suggest the slightly wordier `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("O", Locale.ENGLISH).format(ZoneOffset.UTC)` for this part alone. Then you can embed into the pattern of the real formatter.

Comment: Also what do you do when the OP has got an old-fashioned `Date` and on one hand we want to offer a working example and on the other we don’t want to use the outdated and poorly designed classes unnecessarily? I suggest `Date.from(OffsetDateTime.parse("2023-02-24T19:27:11+05:30").toInstant())`. There are other possibilities without involving `Calendar`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for your feedback. However, I prefer my answer rather than hardcoding `"GMT"` in the pattern. For any timezone, one can simply use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d u H:m:s O", Locale.ENGLISH)` (which would print `Fri Feb 24 2023 19:27:11 GMT` in the case of UTC/GMT). It's just that the OP wanted `00:00` after GMT explicitly, which is not a standard way and therefore I have added `xxx` in the pattern to meet his requirement.

Comment: upvoted the answer. But actually @OleV.V. 's comment to my question helped me solve this. I would rather mark that as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), `O` is `localized zone-offset`. If you take a look into the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, you can find that the `O` option is mapped to a parser called `LocalizedOffsetIdPrinterParser`. Here is the part of the code that makes `GMT` printed without a zone offset:

```
if (totalSecs != 0) {
    ...
}
return true;
```

Since `+00:00` has a `0` total different seconds, this code block is not executed.

Here is an example of how you can use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder#appendOffset(pattern, noOffsetText)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOffset-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to force printing the zone offset even if it's `00:00`:

```
DateTimeFormatterBuilder dateTimeFormatterBuilder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d u H:m:s 'GMT'"))
                .appendOffset("+HH:MM", "+00:00");  // +HH:MM - hour and minute, ignoring second, with colon
DateTimeFormatter formatter = dateTimeFormatterBuilder.toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(odt.format(formatter));
```

Comment: `.appendLiteral("GMT")` is not different from hardcoding `"GMT"` in the pattern as Ole V.V. has already done in a concise way in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75992230/print-gmt0000-in-date/75993831?noredirect=1#comment134030324_75992230). Also, there is no use of `.parseCaseInsensitive()` in this context.

Comment: Appending "GMT" without using `appendLiteral` will cause a problem because `T` is reserved in time formats. "GMT" is also hard-coded in `DateTimeFormatBuilder` there is no problem coding it here too. `parseCaseInsensitive()` is used here to make the formatter able to parse dates too. It's not important for formatting but this formatter can also be used as a parser somewhere else in the code. Also, most JDK built-in formatters use the same approach too.

Comment: Do we need to inspect the source code of the builder to understand this? Allow me to suggest that the documentation of `DateTimeFormatter` that you link to ought to be enough.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I didn't notice that comment before but anyway, there is no problem with using `appendLiteral("GMT")`.